# How to Create Pointy Oval Shape?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, edit-mode, geometry

I have a main character which has this pointy oval shaped

[image: Robot with a pointy oval shaped eye and body]

Right now I am having a lot of trouble to **create the eye and body shape** I just can't figure any way to do it and after searching.

I came here to ask if any of you as any idea of what can be done or a link to usefull ressources regarding my issue.

This is what it looks like right now

[image: Current shape which looks nothing like the reference]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is something like that?

[image]

Comment: It looks good but i cant figure out how to add that sharp edges along the middle and around the eyes

Comment: I've edited, I hope this is closer to what you want?

Comment: This look so simple when you make it ! thanks a lot i'm going to try that out